# Having a struct declaration as the function parameter in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors, asn.1

I'm using [asn1c](http://lionet.info/asn1c/) to generate C++ encoder/decoder codes. There is a problem in the generated code (which is a huge code) preventing it from compile on VC++ which I try to make it simple here:

There is `A_SET_OF` macro in the generated code defined as:

```
#define A_SET_OF(type)                  \
struct {                                \
    type **array;                       \
    int count;  /* Meaningful size */   \
    int size;   /* Allocated size */    \
    void (*free)(type *);               \
}
```

This macro is later used in several parts of code. For instance:

```
A_SET_OF(struct MyStructure {
    long    myNumber;
    char*   myPointer;
} ) myList;
```

I get a `C2226: syntax error : unexpected type` error on these parts. To find what actually is causing the problem, I substituted the actual macro definition:

```
struct {
    struct MyStructure { long myNumber; char* myPointer; } **array;
    int count;  /* Meaningful size */
    int size;   /* Allocated size */    
    void (*free)(struct MyStructure { long myNumber; char* myPointer; } *);
} myList;
```

The error is caused by the `void(*free)` line. Apparently, having struct declaration as a function parameter is a non-standard feature which VC++ do not support (and gcc probably supports as asn1c primary targets Linux).

I am looking for a workaround to this issue, preferably fixing the A_SET_OF macro definition as there are many references to it. `typedef`ing the struct passed to `free` function might solve this issue but I am not sure how it could be done for these anonymous structures.

Comment: You could change the macro to take the name of the type and the definition of the type as two separate parameters.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Hey, Thanks. There are many references inside the code and I have to modify every place `A_SET_OF` is used. Is there any way to do something like your solution while preserving the current usage template of `A_SET_OF` marco?